# Panda dataframe conversion of series of 03Mar2020 date format to 2020-03-03

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm not able to convert input

```
Dates = {'dates': ['05Sep2009','13Sep2011','21Sep2010']}
```

to desired output

```
Dates = {'dates': [2019-09-02,2019-09-13,2019-09-21]}
```

using Pandas Dataframe.

```
data = {'dates': ['05Sep2009','13Sep2011','21Sep2010']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['dates'])
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], format='%Y%m%d')
    
print (df)
```

Output:

```
ValueError: time data '05Sep2009' does not match format '%Y%m%d' (match)
```

I'm new to this library. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Your format `%Y%m%d` expects input like `20090905`. Change your format string to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the months are abbreviated and are not numeric, so you can't use `%m`.
To convert abbreviated months and get the expected output use `%b`, like this:

```
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], format='%d%b%Y')
```

**Update:** to convert the DataFrame back to a dictionary you can use the function `to_dict()` but first, to get the desidered output, you need to convert the column from `datetime` back to `string` type. You can achieve it through this:

```
df['dates'] = df['dates'].astype(str)
df.to_dict('list')
```

Comment: Thank you!. I want the result in dictionary format. Any suggestion for that?

Answer (score 0):

You must change `%m` with `%b`. Because `%m` support month as a zero-padded decimal number. But in you dataframe has a abbreviation of months. Try these code:

```
data = {'dates': ['05Sep2009','13Sep2011','21Sep2010']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['dates'])
df['convert of dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], format='%d%b%Y')
    
display(df)
```

[image: Look]

And also you can check this link about other format:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior